# log4j.properties cannot be found

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I'm having a hard time to get my logger start working.

My log4j.properties file looks like :

```
# Log levels
log4j.rootLogger=INFO,CONSOLE,R
# Appender Configuration
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
# Pattern to output the caller's file name and line number
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n
# Rolling File Appender
log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
# Path and file name to store the log file
log4j.appender.R.File=./logs/testlog.log
log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=200KB
# Number of backup files
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=2
# Layout for Rolling File Appender
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%d - %c - %p - %m%n
```

Taken from 
[this tutorial](http://www.programming-free.com/2012/07/implement-logging-with-log4j-in-java.html)

When i'm printing my classPath, it appears that "C:\Projects\SDK\resources" is one of the directories in the classPath, and that's where my log4j.properties file is.

My logger is initiated as:

```
protected static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("LoggerExmaple");
```

And in my main method i'm trying to :

```
MyClass.logger.warn("bli bla blo");
```

But getting the following error in the console :

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (LoggerExmaple).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

And when i'm trying to do first

```
BasicConfigurator.configure();
```

Then my logger output is

```
0 [main] WARN LoggerExmaple  - bli bla blo
```

My maven dependency for log4j is :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-beta9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-beta9</version>
</dependency>
```

Help anyone?
EDIT:
Answers didn't help. Anyone?

Comment: "log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger" always means that the log4j configuration isn't found in the classpath. Can you precise what you mean by "When i'm printing my classPath"? What exactly do you print? Are you printing the value of System.getProperty("java.class.path") ?

Answer (score 0):

I havent worked with L4J long time but i think that like with Hibernate log4j.prpperties file should be placed inside directory etc inside your project

Answer (score 0):

You need to define WARN appender in log4j.properties. You have only INFO, CONSOLE and R appenders and you are trying to access WARN. Try adding these lines to your log4j.properties file

```
log4j.appender.WARN=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.WARN.File=./logs/testlog.log
log4j.appender.WARN.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.WARN.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n
```

and change

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO,CONSOLE,R,WARN
```